# edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException error using Stanford nlp POS tagger

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, buildpath

I am currently configuring my Java project in order to use Stanford's POS tagger. However I am currently getting the following 2 errors when running the program.

The first being:

```
Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Error while loading a tagger model (probably missing model file)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:791)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:312)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:265)
at TagText.main(TagText.java:10)
```

And the second being:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "taggers/left3words-distsim-wsj-0-18.tagger" as class path, filename or URL
at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:470)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:789)
... 3 more
```

I am using the example found here to build test the POS tagger:

http://new.galalaly.me//2011/05/tagging-text-with-stanford-pos-tagger-in-java-applications/

Comment: This is a good summary of the API: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html , I would not refer to that link if its from 2011 that is somewhat out of date.  Also make sure to get the latest version 3.7.0 !!

Comment: Here is a link to where you can download resources: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution if anyone else ever needs it. You need to make sure that your MaxentTagger tagger has the correct and updated english file passing through it.